# multiple custom carousels that dont control each other

Tags: jquery, html, carousel

I'm pretty new to JQuery / JavaScript but I made a carousel for a website and I want to know how to make the buttons control their respective carousels.

heres a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z6q6bgzq/

HTML -

```
<div>
  <div class="carousel-slide">
    <div class="focus">
      SLIDE 1
    </div>
    <div>
      SLIDE 2
    </div>
    <div>
      SLIDE 3
    </div>
    <div>
      SLIDE 4
    </div>
    <div>
      SLIDE 5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative; top:20px;">
    <button class="arrow left">&lt;---</button>
    <button class="arrow right">---></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position: relative; top:20px;">
  <div class="carousel-slide">
    <div class="focus">
      SLIDE 1
    </div>
    <div>
      SLIDE 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: relative; top:20px;">
    <button class="left">&lt;---</button>
    <button class="right">---></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".right").click(function(){
        var $next = $(".focus").removeClass("focus").next("div",".carousel-slide");
        if ($next.length){
            $next.addClass("focus");
        }else{
            $("div:first",".carousel-slide").addClass("focus");
        }
    });

    $(".left").click(function){
        var $prev = $(".focus").removeClass("focus").prev("div",".carousel-slide");
        if ($prev.length){
            $prev.addClass("focus");
        }else{
            $("div:last",".carousel-slide").addClass("focus");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This should help a bit http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/1321/events/14028/events-for-repeating-elements-without-using-ids#t=201612202212510390579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
    
        $(".right").click(function(e){
            
            var $next = $(this).parent().prev().find(".focus").removeClass("focus").next("div");
            if ($next.length){
                $next.addClass("focus");
            }else{
               $(this).parent().prev().children().first().addClass("focus");
            }
        });

        $(".left").click(function(e){
            var $prev = $(this).parent().prev().find(".focus").removeClass("focus").prev("div");
            if ($prev.length){
                $prev.addClass("focus");
            }else{
                $(this).parent().prev().children().last().addClass("focus");
            }
        });
});
```

```css
.carousel-slide > div{
    transition: opacity 400ms;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.carousel-slide > .focus{
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            
            <div class="carousel-slide"> <!--previous -->
                <div class="focus">
                    SLIDE 1
                </div>
                <div>
                    SLIDE 2
                </div>
                <div>
                    SLIDE 3
                </div>
                <div>
                    SLIDE 4
                </div>
                <div>
                    SLIDE 5
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="position: relative; top:20px;"> <!--parent-->
                <button class="arrow left">&lt;---</button>
                <button class="arrow right">---></button>
            </div>
             
            
            <div style="position: relative; top:20px;">
            <div class="carousel-slide">
                <div class="focus">
                    SLIDE 1
                </div>
                <div>
                    SLIDE 2
                </div>
            </div>
              <div style="position: relative; top:20px;">
                  <button class="left">&lt;---</button>
                  <button class="right">---></button>
              </div>
           
</div>
```

So, you have to change selectors ($prev/$next vars) and few other things, accordingly. I made comments in HTML for easier understanding. You have to traverse through DOM, to find parent buttons div, and previous sibling. Now, when selectors are not 'greedy' (you aren't targeting all divs with .carousel-slide class on page), all should work fine.

P.S. If you keep current HTML structure, you can add more carousels, this way.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you need something to identify carousel 1 from carousel 2? That's where an ID come in.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

        $("#C1Right").click(function(e){
            var $next = $("#carousel1 .focus").removeClass("focus").next("div",".carousel-slide");
           if ($next.length){
                $next.addClass("focus");
            }else{
                $("div:first","#carousel1 .carousel slide").addClass("focus");
            }
        });

        $("#C1Left").click(function(e){
            var $prev = $("#carousel1 .focus").removeClass("focus").prev("div",".carousel-slide");
            if ($prev.length){
                $prev.addClass("focus");
            }else{
                $("div:last","#carousel1 .carousel-slide").addClass("focus");
            }
    });

$("#C2Right").click(function(e){
            var $next = $("#carousel2 .focus").removeClass("focus").next("div",".carousel-slide");
            if ($next.length){
                $next.addClass("focus");
            }else{
                $("div:first","#carousel2 .carousel-slide").addClass("focus");
            }
        });

        $("#C2Left").click(function(e){
            var $prev = $("#carousel2 .focus").removeClass("focus").prev("div",".carousel-slide");
            if ($prev.length){
                $prev.addClass("focus");
            }else{
                $("div:last","#carousel2 .carousel-slide").addClass("focus");
            }
        });


    });
```